# Mongodb: insert or update *field*

Tags: mongodb

I need an Update command that can check if a field is defined, and if it is, $inc, otherwise, $set. How can I do it?

For example, I have a user, and I want to update the # of times other people called. So at first, User is:

```
User = { userName: "name", callers: {}}
```

After a phone call, I add the new caller id to callers:

```
User = { userName: "name", callers: { "otherUser": 1 }}
```

The problem is that I want to update the number of calls from the "otherUser", s.t if he called again, I'll have:

```
User = { userName: "name", callers: { "otherUser": 2 }}
```

Comment: But the callers are dynamically added, it makes no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whatever you need is automatically done by *$inc*, no need to explicitly check whether field is defined or not.**

try

```
db.users.update({userName:"name"},{$inc:{"callers.otherUser":1}},true)
```

*or*

```
db.users.update({userName:"name"},{$inc:{"callers.otherUser":1}})
```

Assumption : users is your **collection**

### Explanation

$inc is operator which increment a field by specified value. **If field does not exist it will add the field to document.**
syntax is

```
$inc:{field:value}
```

In your case, you want to update a field that is in a sub-document `callers:{}`. In order to access it you have to have use `sub-document-name.field` that what I used `callers.otherUser`

If want to go in depth here are reference :

- [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)
- [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but can you explain a little why this would work, or point me to the relevant documentation?

Comment: explained..visit reference for more info. links are in answer

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation :)